# Android studio giving errors when trying to launch an app

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

Tried to Run my App on my phone through a USB cable, and it wont launch(the same thing is on emulator). Tried Invalidating caches and restarting, cloning git project again(it resulted in my files saying that the target uri for material.dart doesnt exist, which of course made everything be considered an error), Pub get, upgrade, flutter clean, to no avail. Below i have flutter doctor and console results, as well as my dependencies. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the output of `flutter build apk --v`

Comment: It's unable to create a jar file, more info is needed. Maybe a storage space issue? if on Windows trying running Android Studio with administrator privileges.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NKH5kF5M here is a pastebin link to that flutter build apk -v command, and no, it doesnt seem like a storage issue, i still have 5.8 gb left on my C drive